# Defining a function within a class in Python 2.7

Tags: python, function, class

I tried to add a pgdc function in the `Fraction` class in order to calculate the biggest common divided or a number `pgdc` ... The function should be recursive. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jf/Desktop/Python-jEdit_v2/23_fraction.py", line 60, in <module>
    p = a.plus(b)
  File "C:/Users/jf/Desktop/Python-jEdit_v2/23_fraction.py", line 35, in plus
    return resultat.simplifier()
  File "C:/Users/jf/Desktop/Python-jEdit_v2/23_fraction.py", line 27, in simplifier
    p = pgcd(self.num, self.den)
NameError: global name 'pgcd' is not defined
```

In addition,

I also got the following error for the `simplifier` : `AttributeError: Fraction instance has no attribute 'simplifier'`

Which, leave me puzzle, as I tried to `add self.pgcd=pgcd` and `self.simplifier=simplifier`

at various places and it still did not work well...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Fraction():
    # constructeur et attributs

    def __init__(self, num = 0, den = 1):
        self.num = num

        if (den == 0):
            erreur("Dénominateur nul") #fonction d'erreur
        self.den = den

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.den)

    def erreur(message):
        print "Erreur: " + message
        from sys import exit
        exit()
    def pgcd(a, b):
        if a == b: 
           return a
        if a > b: 
            return pgcd(a-b, b)
        else: 
            return pgcd(a, b-a)
    def simplifier(self):
        p = pgcd(self.num, self.den)
        self.num = self.num / p
        self.den = self.den / p
        return self

    def plus(self, f):
        resultat = Fraction(self.num * f.den + self.den * f.num, \
                            self.den * f.den)
        return resultat.simplifier()
    def moins(self, f):
        resultat = Fraction(self.num * f.den - self.den * f.num, \
            self.den * f.den)
        if (resultat.num < 0):
        # changer de signe avant de simplifier
            resultat.num = - resultat.num
            resultat = resultat.simplifier()
            resultat.num = - resultat.num
            return resultat
        else:
            return resultat.simplifier()

    def fois(self, f):
        resultat = Fraction(self.num * f.num, self.den * f.den)
        return resultat.simplifier()
    def div(self, f):
        resultat = Fraction(self.num * f.den, self.den * f.num)
        return resultat.simplifier()



#### CONSOLE ####
a = Fraction(5, 11)
b = Fraction(3, 7)
p = a.plus(b)
```

Comment: does this help:  def pgcd(self, a, b):  also: return self.pgcd(...

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel: `from fractions import gcd`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `self` as a parameter of your function and use it when you want to recursively call `pgcd`:

```
def pgcd(self,a, b):
    if a == b: 
       return a
    if a > b: 
        return self.pgcd(a-b, b)
    else: 
        return self.pgcd(a, b-a)
```

Also, call `pgcd` with `self.` on this line:

```
p = self.pgcd(self.num, self.den)  #from pgcd(self.num, self.den)
```